# i want know system system localhost IP address in PHP?

Tags: php

here i am using `$_SERVER['remote_addr']` i am getting the IP address INTERNET providers. please help me out.

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: What IP are you trying to get?  The server?  The client?  I suggest `var_dump($_SERVER)`, and then finding the one you want.

Comment: Please make an effort to use correct English.

Comment: The title suggests you looking for the localhost IP, which is 127.0.0.1

Comment: i used that one var_dump($_SERVER) i didn't get any solution

Comment: i need IP address of the system when i am using `$_SERVER['remote_addr']` i am getting common gateway IP address means that INTERNET public IP address , her i have 10 systems getting same IP addresses , i do not want that one i want system IP address

Comment: @pardhu You're using the same language over and over to explain your problem and it's clear that people don't understand. Stop using the term `System` (everything is a 'system') - instead use Client(Browser) and Server(Apache/PHP).

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the question is looking for the server's IP address, and the problem is that the supplied code is returning the remote IP.  If you want the IP address of the server, try `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` .  See [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for more details, or clearly define what you mean by "system IP".

Comment: its not giving any IP address , i don't want server IP address i want system local IPv4 address

Comment: As Mike B says - nobody understands what you mean by "system IP".  Your server has an IP, and the request has an IP.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get the client's local IP address from PHP like this, you will only ever get the

> common gateway IP address

as you put it.  This is because the request will appear to be coming from the router or whatever is between your client and the web server